# Fock states and the expectation value of the Field operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space

I have been reading a bit on Fock and Coherent states in context of bosons (specifically Bose - Einstein condensates, and the Bose - Hubbard model in optical lattices)

It is stated that for Fock states
$$\langle \hat{\Psi}\rangle_\text{Fock}=0$$

I am not able to prove this explicitly. More specifically, what is the expansion for the field operator (I want to consider an inhomogenous system, so do not want to consider the Fourier transform to $k$ space)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the operator $\hat{\Psi}$ will be more familiar in the context of the harmonic oscillator, where we define the analogous operator $\hat{a}$ (usually termed the 'lowering' operator). A Fock state $|n\rangle$ is equivalent to the $n$-th eigenstate of the corresponding harmonic oscillator.

The action of $\hat{\Psi}$ on a Fock state is $\hat{\Psi}|n\rangle = \sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle$. Therefore the expectation value of the operator for a Fock state is given by:
$$
\langle n|\hat{\Psi}|n\rangle = \sqrt{n} \langle n | n-1\rangle = 0
$$